# Is there a way to avoid creating huge amount of interfaces and classes in the Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, tdd

My development pattern is as follows:

1. I need functionality
2. I create an interface
3. I create an empty class that implements that interface
4. I build the implementation by way of TDD (using Mockito), following steps 1 through 3 for functionality that it relies on

This results in a huge amount of interfaces with single implementation classes. Does there exist a shortcut, a better way?

---

**Update**

Based on the comments I found out that Mockito can be used to mock classes (don't laugh at me). I made a little experiment. Here's the UML:

[image: UML]

Here's the relevant code (all classes, no interfaces):

```
public class MessageGetter {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Real Hello";
    }

}

public class MessageDisplayer {

    public void displayMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}

public class MessageWriter {

    private MessageGetter messageGetter;
    private MessageDisplayer messageDisplayer;

    public void setMessageGetter(MessageGetter messageGetter) {
        this.messageGetter = messageGetter;
    }

    public void setMessageDisplayer(MessageDisplayer messageDisplayer) {
        this.messageDisplayer = messageDisplayer;
    }

    public void writeMessage() {
        String message = messageGetter.getMessage();
        messageDisplayer.displayMessage(message);
    }

}
```

So, using Mockito I was able to test MessageWriter.writeMessage() without a single interface:

```
public class MessageWriterTest {

    @Test
    public void testWriteMessage() {
        MessageGetter mockMessageGetter = mock(MessageGetter.class);
        MessageDisplayer mockMessageDisplayer = mock(MessageDisplayer.class);

        String mockMessage = "Mock Hello";

        when(mockMessageGetter.getMessage()).thenReturn(mockMessage);

        MessageWriter messageWriter = new MessageWriter();
        messageWriter.setMessageGetter(mockMessageGetter);
        messageWriter.setMessageDisplayer(mockMessageDisplayer);

        messageWriter.writeMessage();

        verify(mockMessageDisplayer).displayMessage(mockMessage);
    }

}
```

I've been creating interfaces in Spring Framework for so long that I don't know if it's okay not to. Is it okay to stop?

Comment: While coding vs. Interfaces tends to be a good idea, nobody actually forces you to. None of your steps above actually stricly **require** an Interface. You can wire Beans without interfaces, you can mock classes (as long as they aren't `final`)...

Comment: [YAGNI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Check out [Do I need to use an interface when only one class will ever implement it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it)

Comment: When unit testing, you can use your concrete implementations in many cases. You do not need to mock every collaborator.

Comment: My large Spring web application does not have numerous interfaces and classes.

Comment: @Raedwald (1) You need to mock collaborators so that you can control what they return, I think that it doesn't make sense what you said in regards to unit tests, and (2) how could your large Spring Web App not have numerous classes, where does your code reside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like when using Spring and Mockito life can be simpler. I've farther simplified my code from what I posted in the question. The basic idea is that:

1. We don't need setter methods
2. We can automatically create mocks in the unit test
3. We can automatically inject the mocks in the unit test
4. No interfaces are needed

Here are the dependencies in pom.xml for this example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are the 2 Components:

```
@Component
public class MessageDisplayer {

    public void displayMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}

@Component
public class MessageGetter {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Real Hello";
    }

}
```

Here is the class that I'm testing:

```
public class MessageWriter {

    @Autowired
    private MessageGetter messageGetter;

    @Autowired
    private MessageDisplayer messageDisplayer;

    public void writeMessage() {
        String message = messageGetter.getMessage();
        messageDisplayer.displayMessage(message);
    }

}
```

And here is the test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MessageWriterTest {

    @Mock
    private MessageGetter mockMessageGetter;

    @Mock
    private MessageDisplayer mockMessageDisplayer;

    @InjectMocks
    private MessageWriter messageWriter;

    @Test
    public void testWriteMessage() {
        String mockMessage = "Mock Hello";
        when(mockMessageGetter.getMessage()).thenReturn(mockMessage);
        messageWriter.writeMessage();
        verify(mockMessageDisplayer).displayMessage(mockMessage);
    }

}
```